# ClearBox 3 jQuery.noConflict(); and/or javascript conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

I've been trying to make this [script](http://pastebin.com/5zZRV6ex) from [ClearBox3](https://web.archive.org/web/20120919094306/http://www.clearbox.hu:80/index_en.html) to stop conflicting with [MooTools](https://mootools.net/core/builder/76bf47062d6c1983d66ce47ad66aa0e0).. But I can't seem to find a solution on google on how to do this.

Expected (Removed mootools library) - Displays Modal Window
[image: expected]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/hf1foynk.pvf.png))</sub>

Actual (Joomla 2.5 Enviroment) - Redirects me to the image and does not display a modal window.
[image: actual]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/zn2j3gxi.fpi.png))</sub>

So far I've ran the code `jQuery.noConflict();` and I've swapped the function calls with `$` with `jQuery.`, But I'm being met with the error `missing ( before formal parameters line 1`.

[image: Missing Formal]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/rpqr0ymo.nso.png))</sub>

Here is a modification of the script [here](http://pastebin.com/mMbeRAJj).

Update: Unsure if its jquery conflicting.. due to implementing this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3qWN/) (Thanks [Joseph Silber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825568/joseph-silber)) and new errors are occuring..

```
 Timestamp: 26/06/2012 3:22:34 p.m.
 Error: Event[cb[73]] is undefined
 Source File: http://localhost/components/com_autobase/js/clearbox/core/cb_core.js
 Line: 4
```

So the question is ... how can I stop the conflicting? between ClearBox3 and MooTools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to replace all the `$` symbols. Just create a closure:

```
(function($) {
    // put all the code in here,
    // the $ will refer to the local variable containing jQuery
})( jQuery.noConflict() );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3qWN/

Comment: Hey I'm unsure how to implement this.. I put the original code in the critical section and tried once without replacing `$` and again but with replacing `$` with `jQuery`. And both the times the Error Console came back with `jQuery is not defined` (pastebin available [here](http://pastebin.com/2pq0prE0)) :-/ any other ideas? thank you

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it on the line containing `jQuery.noConflict()`? Are you sure you have jQuery loaded on the page?

Comment: Okay so I didn't have jquery loaded but after I loaded it from [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js) on googles api, I now get the error `Event[cb[73]] is undefined Line 4`, I have no idea on why it is still conflicting :/

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't replace `$` with `jQuery.`, just `jQuery`.

You could also try

```
JQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then replace all the `$` with `JQ`, which will be your local sign.

Comment: Hey as joseph pointed out, from the jQuery error I was having.. I now think its javascript that is conflicting with mootools? any other suggestions? I'm at a loss lol. I did try your answer and error console isn't coming back with any errors but at the same time the clearbox isn't working it just directs me to the url of the image but not a modal window containing the image. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was with `mootools` overwriting some variables used in `clearbox` on joomla 2.5.

by using the `$document->addCustomTag('<script src="js/clearbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');`. This declares underneath `mootools` instead of above.